# What is $E(\min\{X,Y\}\vert Y)$ where $X\sim\text{Exp}_\alpha$ and $Y$ is an arbitrary positive-real-valued RV?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-expectation

What is $E(\min\{X,Y\}\vert Y)$ where $X\sim\text{Exp}_\alpha$ and $Y$ is an arbitrary positive-real-valued RV?

It is clear that $\min\{X,Y\}$ is integrable, and also the following holds
$$E(\min\{X,Y\}\vert Y) = E(1_{X\le Y} X\vert Y)+E(1_{X>Y}Y\lvert Y)$$
but I don't see how I can proceed without any knowledge what so ever about $Y$.

Comment: The answer would be in terms of $Y$. In other words. $E(min(X,Y)|Y)$ is a function of $Y$.

Comment: Maybe the notation is throwing you off. $E(\min\{X,Y\}|Y)$ means $E(\min\{X,Y\}|Y=y)$ for some positive value $y$.